# how to run a program using command line with parameters on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, scanner, api

I'm trying to use [APIKit](http://ericasadun.com/2009/12/apikit-goes-beta/) to scan my codes to detect if there is private API.  *apiscanner* should run as

```
apiscanner ~/Desktop/MyPath/myapp.app
```

I used command 'cd' go to the directory where apiscanner is.  But if I call `apiscanner ~/Desktop/MyPath/MyApp.app` on terminal it reports

```
Last login: Sun Jun 13 07:22:07 on ttys002
  unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT trap
logout
```

Even if I copy the files *apiscanner* and *doit* to *MyPath*, then execute, I get the same problem.  I think there is something wrong when I run *apiscanner* under Mac OS X.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Comment: Generally when you run `command`, it searches system directories for the command. If you wish to use a command in the current directory, use `./command` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the command correctly if you are simply trying to pass `~/Desktop/MyPath/myapp.app` as the first argument to the command `apiscanner` - and the command will work from any directory on your system assuming that `apiscanner` is installed correctly.

The output you are seeing is legitimate output from `apiscanner`, and you should check that it is fully supported for your version of OS X and properly installed.

If you're still having troubles, you can almost always google the application name and the error message - `Mac apiscanner unknown required load command 0x80000022`, or you can alter your question / ask a new one here to clarify what you're having trouble with.